# Form_for sub-resource throws an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

I have two models: `Point` and `PointPage`. `Point has_many :point_pages` and `PointPage belongs_to :point`.

In `routes.rb`

```
resources :points do
  resources :point_pages
end
```

When creating `Point` rails creates two `PointPages`, belonging to that point.

In `point_pages_controller.rb`

```
def index
  point = Point.find(params[:point_id])
  @page_from = point.point_pages.find_by(page_type_from: true)
  @page_to = point.point_pages.find_by(page_type_from: false)
end
```

So, I need to show both `PointPages` (`@page_from` and `@page_to`) for certain `Point` on one `index` page. And I need to allow users to edit these `PointPages` on that one page. But when I create `form_for @page_from` and `form_for @page_to` on this `index` page, I get an error:

```
undefined method `point_page_path' for #<#<Class ... >>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your action to be like this:

```
def index
  @point = Point.find(params[:point_id])
  @page_from = point.point_pages.find_by(page_type_from: true)
  @page_to = point.point_pages.find_by(page_type_from: false)
end
```

This way you will have the @point

And in your view you should create the forms like this:

```
form_for [@point, @page_from]
```

and

```
form_for [@point, @page_to]
```

When you have nested routes you need to adjust the form_for object to work properly. You can see more details here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html